# What does the GEGL Operation in GIMP do?

Tags: images, gimp, processing

I see it under the Tools menu, but I've never used it before. What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses [GEGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GEGL) for an experimental operation - GEGL was supposed to replace GIMP's core image handler in 2000, but it only proved stable in ~2006.

This is mainly for developers I believe, as GEGL is still considered experimental.